# Rotate photo in moderncv

Tags: graphics, moderncv, rotating

I'm doing my CV with the template ModernCV Classic. I want to rotate my picture but the command used is `\photo` I don't know how to do that.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\nopagenumbers{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{...}
\address{adress}{Town}{Country}

\extrainfo{age, nationality}
\phone[mobile]{54466145745}
\email{john.doe@mail.com}
\photo[80pt][0.4pt]{Photo.jpg}
\quote{Objectifs: ...}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why don't just rotate the picture with an image editor outside of LaTeX?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3):

You  can patch `\makecvhead` using the `xpatch` package to inject the angle of rotation.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}%
   {width=\@photowidth}%
   {width=\@photowidth,angle=90}%
   {}{}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{...}
\address{adress}{Town}{Country}

\extrainfo{age, nationality}
\phone[mobile]{54466145745}
\email{john.doe@mail.com}
\photo[80pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\quote{Objectifs: ...}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```